# iMacros loop and report crash

Tags: imacros

I made some iMacros script and I want it to let me know (send an email) if it fails to finish it. More specifically, I made a website and made iMacros check it,go through it in an infinite loop (every half an hour) and my question is: Is it possible to make iMacros to send me an alert that something is wrong?? Example:Unable to connect,website no longer in function or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

possible, but not with regular imacros IIM.
you'll need to create code which check your site and code which sends email , unite it together and run with infinite loop.
Use javascript or similar.